# Eclipse shortcuts in Resharper

Tags: resharper

I just started with Visual Studio + Resharper, coming from Java development with Eclipse. I can navigate eclipse pretty quickly, because I memorized all the shortcuts I need. Now it seems like Resharper knows all what eclipse can do (probably even more), but its mapped to different keys, and i really don't feel like learning a new set of shortcuts for the same stuff.

So my question:

1. **Where is Resharpers shortcut configuration file** (if there is any)? I saw a bunch of `.xml` files in it's bin directory, but I'm not sure it's the right place to look. Couldn't find anything in the docs, only how to change the shortcuts from VS one-by-one.
2. **Is there an eclipse preset?** I found [this](https://github.com/chrismo/jetbrains.keymaps/blob/master/resharper.5.0.eclipse.shortcuts.vs2010.vssettings) on github, but there is absolutely no explanation, on what to do with it, and in the file name it states, it's for r# 5.0 and i have 8.1 (not sure if there is any difference in the configuration part).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resharper comes with only two default keyboard schemes, 'Visual Studio' or 'IntelliJ IDEA' ([see here](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Reference__Keyboard_Shortcuts.html)). Choose one that you are most happy with (under `Resharper`->`Options...`->`Environment`->`Keyboard & Menus`) and change any shortcuts in Visual Studio (under `Tools`->`Options...`->`Environment`->`Keyboard`) to match the ones in Eclipse. It may be easier just to re-learn one of the default schemes though.

Comment: So there is no configuration file, where i could mass-edit the keyboard shortcuts? I saw these options, and also tried the ui for editing individual key bindings, but because it saves it god knows where, i cannot restore my settings if get a new computer, a fresh installation, etc.

Comment: you can save your Visual Studio settings using `Tools`->`Import and Export Settings...`

Answer (score 4):

I found this file using Google Search: https://github.com/chrismo/jetbrains.keymaps/blob/master/resharper.5.0.eclipse.shortcuts.vs2010.vssettings

You can download it and use Visual Studio's Tools -> Import and Export Settings ... command to import it.

Comment: Great answer: working perfect in VS.2017 (communauty edition)